# How to automatically sort SPListItems based on a field

Tags: sharepoint, list

I have a requirement that a SPList should be sorted by the "Priority" field (number field, no limits) when a ListItem is added or updated.

The sort should work as this:

```
Original        Inserted item         Modified
   1                                      1
   2                2                     2
   3                                      3 (old 2)
                                          4 (old 3)
```

Edited: This behaviour is primary for improving the user experience when editing data in the data sheet view. 
It is a sort of a poor mans AJAX style updates that I am trying to get.

The only solution I see right now is to use an event handler and update the ListItems that should be deprioritized, however that could be a fairly costly operation on a list with hundreds of items (unless there are gaps in the sequence).

Have I missed the obvious solution, or a far better scaling way?

tia

Comment: It is now in production, and the performance is ok up to about 200 items in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, tough one.  I do not like the idea of going back and doing updates to existing items from a EventReceiver.  You are asking for trouble.

Here is my recomendation.

Use 2 fields for your sort.

1 your priorty field as you have it today (so someone says 1, 2 , 3, 4)... 
2 the create date field (this is a builtin datetime field).

so your results would look something like this

1 1/1/2009 
2 5/16/2009 
2 5/11/2009 
3 5/12/2009

Comment: JD, I like your idea but it doesn't solve the problem, at least now right away. If I can't make the "update all conflicting items" algoritm perform I might use your suggestion as a temp solution and then update the items async later on

Comment: Kasper You should check out the SharePoint 2007 Meeting template.  It has a list to support Agenda's that does something similar.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the items sorted in a view:
Set the sort order in the view.

If you want items sorted when using the SharePoint API:
Use a SPQuery with an OrderBy element. http://sharepointmagazine.net/technical/development/writing-caml-queries-for-retrieving-list-items-from-a-sharepoint-list